# Prove that $A = B$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I want to prove that $A = B$ iff $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$. I'm unsure of how to approach this problem. It seems really easy but I have no idea. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go by definition what does it mean $A$ belongs to $B$

Comment: Each element of A belongs to B and each element of B belongs to A. Thus, they must have the same elements?

EDIT: Is going by definition sufficient as a proof?

Comment: Complete the sentence: Suppose $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$. Then...

Comment: Suppose A $\subseteq$ B and B $\subseteq$ A. Then A = B?

Comment: To prove that A = B you basically have to prove both those things. What definition of subset are you using, and what definition of set equality? This proof doesn't actually require much more than writing down the definitions of everything.

Comment: @Monofu If you are just starting your study of mathematical methods of proof, I would recommend you to have a look at Velleman's *How to Prove It*. Good read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I start from a suggestion of user180040

Suppose that A=B.  Then suppose x $\in$A.  It follows that x $\in$B.  Why?  Because

anytime we have an equality, we can replace any instance of one side of the equality by

the other side of the equality wherever it appears in any statement.  Thus, we can infer

that x $\in$A implies x $\in$B.  Since it holds that "if x $\in$A, then x$\in$B", by

definition, we then obtain that A$\subseteq$B.  Similarly, we can prove that

B$\subseteq$A.  Thus, both A$\subseteq$B and B$\subseteq$A.  So, we can infer that if

A=B, then both A$\subseteq$B and B$\subseteq$A. End of first part.

Now suppose that A$\subseteq$B and B$\subseteq$A.  By definition of $\subseteq$ and since

we have that A$\subseteq$B, we have that

"if x $\in$A, then x $\in$B".  Similarly, we can infer that "if x $\in$B, then x

$\in$A."  So, we can infer that x $\in$A if and only if x $\in$B.  Since we've proved the

antecedent of the [axiom of extensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), we can infer the consequent that A=B.

Thus we can infer that, if A$\subseteq$B and B$\subseteq$A, then A=B.  End of second part.

Since we've proved that "if A=B, then A$\subseteq$B and B$\subseteq$A" and "if A$\subseteq$B and B$\subseteq$A, then A=B" we can infer that

A=B iff A⊆B and B⊆A.

Comment: Okay, so you've explicitly proved that $\forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B) \land \forall x (x \in B \rightarrow x \in A)$ implies $\forall x (x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B)$, so as to apply the axiom of extensionality. You're right that this is something else that would need to be done in a formal proof.

Comment: User180040, you say this is something else that would need to be done in a formal proof. What else is left?

Comment: By a formal proof I mean one that follows precise syntax and rules of deduction such as the ones described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus I imagine that there will be other steps, like applying the modus ponens, invoking logical axioms, etc., but I'd rather not work out the details. My overall point is that these are minute details of logic and not anything to do with set theory.

Comment: @user135367 For what's left, you would write out an axiom set for predicate calculus with equality with an appropriate set of axioms for a set theory.  Then without using any other meta-theory than comes as needed to set up that axiom set and the axioms of set theory, you would formally prove the claim symbolically.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

**1)** If $A=B$, clearly $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.

**2)** Suppose that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$. If $A \not= B$, then there exists $x \in A\setminus B$(or $x \in B\setminus A$), however $A \subseteq B$, clearly $x\in B$. This is a contradiction. So $A=B$.

Comment: I believe your claim that, since $A \ne B$, there must be an $x$ that belongs to one of $A$ or $B$, but not the other, implicitly appeals to the very fact you are setting out to prove.

Answer (score 3):

When you have to show something of "Property one holds if and only if property two holds", you approach it in the following way (and this is especially true for introductory level problems, like this one):

1. You remember that in order to prove an "if and only if" statement, you need to show two implications hold. First you assume that property one holds, and you show that property two holds, and then the other way around.
2. You open up your notes, book, or whatever, and you write down on a piece of paper the definitions for both property one and property two. In this case, you write down explicitly what does it mean that $A\subseteq B$ and what does it mean that $A=B$.
3. You finish up the proof in the two big steps, each requiring about two smaller steps to prove.

Answer (score 3):

The forward implication really asks you to prove that $A \subseteq A$. That's true because for any $x \in A$, it's true that $x \in A$.

The reverse implication, that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ implies $A = B$, is actually an axiom of set theory called the "axiom of extensionality." Therefore the "proof" would simply amount to quoting the axiom.

I doubt that this answer is actually what's expected here, but I think it's highly likely that other "proofs" will involve some form of circular reasoning, or else "definitions" of set equality that are logically deficient in some way.

I have seen books that define two sets to be equal when they have the same elements. However it does not follow from this "definition" of equality that any property that is true of the first set must necessarily be true of the second, since "equal," having been defined, cannot be taken with its ordinary meaning of "being identical." Without the axiom of extensionality, it does not follow from the fact that two sets have the same elements that they are identical in other respects.

Comment: There's more to the proof than just quoting the axiom of extensionality, though referencing it makes for a good tip.  The forward implication is also more involved.

Comment: Well, there would be logical niceties like substituting the particular variables denoting $A$ and $B$ we have for whatever variables happened to appear in the statement of the axiom. Nothing beyond that. For the forward implication, to get to the point I mentioned, you need to use the fact that if $A = B$, then any property of $A$ is also true of $B$, so $A \subseteq A$ implies $A \subseteq B$. But these details are really at a microscopic level, and they essentially concern only logic, not set theory. If you disagree, perhaps you can spell out what you mean.

Comment: I've posted an answer to indicate what I mean, and used the Wikipedia on the axiom of extensionality.  The axiom of extensionality is an implication (though I did find one reference that indicates it as an equivalence), with its antecedent as an equivalence.  How do you get to the consequent?  If you prove the equivalence, then you can infer the consequent by detachment.  The OP's right hand side of the equivalence has a conjunction.  Thus, it's not the axiom of extensionality.

Comment: I have to admit that I overstated my case. There are some logical manipulations that need to be done. However, I maintain that as a matter of pure logic, the forward implication consists of combining a tautology with an axiom of equality, and uses no set theory facts; and the reverse implication is *logically* equivalent to the axiom of extensionality, again without using any set theory facts. Replacing the inclusion relation with its definition in terms of $=$ and $\in$ should not count as a step.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\notag \\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$Here is how I would prove this, simply and succinctly.  We start at the most complex side of the statement, expand the definitions, and simplify, as follows:

$$\calc
A \subseteq B \;\land\; B \subseteq A
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\subseteq\;$, twice}
\langle \forall x :: x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B \rangle \;\land\; \langle \forall x :: x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: merge the $\;\forall x \;$ quantifications into one}
\langle \forall x :: (x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B) \;\land\; (x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A) \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: simplify mutual implication to equivalence}
\langle \forall x :: x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in B \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;=\;$, i.e., set extensionality}
A = B
\endcalc$$

Answer (score 0):

For the forward implication, assume $A=B$. Then for any $x \in A$, $x \in B$ and thus $A \subseteq B$. Similarly, if $x \in B$, then $x \in A$ and thus $B \subseteq A$. Now using similar tactics approach the reverse implication.